# Interpretation of summary of a hierarchical logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, interpretation

I'd like to know if my interpretation of this summary is correct.

It is a hierarchical logistic regression I made with mixed models for an analysis of a generalization gradient. I've got fixed and random effects.

The variables are the following:

a) Group: group CONTROL is the intercept. The other group is INTERV. it's a FACTOR variable.

b) TIME: TIME = 1 is the intercept, and was the first time the data was collected. The other time is TIME = 2.  It's a FACTOR variable.

c) SIMILARITY: it's a NUMERIC variable. It's the similarity of one stimulus to another one.

d) CHOICE: it is an INTEGER variable. The "choices" can be 0 or 1.

e) id: number of identification for each subject in the study. It is a FACTOR.

The code I used in R and summary:

```
model <- glmer(choice ~ (1+similarity|id) + group*time*similarity,
                   data = data,
                   family = binomial(link="logit"),
                   control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
                   nAGQ = 1)

Summary:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)                       0.7344     0.3534   2.078 0.037666 *  
groupINTERV                      -2.3423     0.5218  -4.489 7.15e-06 ***
time                              0.2049     0.1018   2.012 0.044191 *  
similarity                        0.3790     0.1882   2.013 0.044063 *  
groupINTERV:time                  1.3925     0.2018   6.902 5.14e-12 ***
groupINTERV:similarity           -0.6144     0.2996  -2.050 0.040316 *  
time:similarity                   0.3519     0.1056   3.332 0.000862 ***
groupINTERV:time:similarity       0.2337     0.1976   1.183 0.236840
```

1. In TIME = 1 with SIMILARITY = 0, CHOICE is greater for INTERV group than for CONTROL group.
2. CHOICE was positively influenced by TIME for CONTROL group (when SIMILARITY = 0)
3. For CONTROL group, in TIME = 1, the greater is SIMILARITY, the greater CHOICE is. In other words: for CONTROL group, in TIME = 1, SIMILARITY influences positively in CHOICE.
4. INTERV group was more positively influenced by TIME in CHOICE than the CONTROL group.
5. In TIME = 1, the effect of SIMILARITY is greater in CONTROL group than in INTERV group.
6. In both group s, the rise in TIME increased SIMILARITY's influence in CHOICE.

Comment: I highly suggest you use something like `ggeffects` or `marginaleffects` to plot this interaction. E.g., `int <- ggeffects(model, terms = c("time", "similarity[0,.2,.4,.6,.8,1]", "groupINTERV"))` `ggplot(int, aes(x, predicted, colour = group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~facet)` or you can try `plot(int)` See https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html#two-way-three-way--and-four-way-interactions

Comment: I used here ggeffects and it helped me a lot to visualize the interactions. It provides the means to create very useful graphs. Thank you very much for your suggestion!